# Making personalize stack with personalized class but error shows up

Tags: c++

Hi I wanted to make my personal stack class with template
and make a stack with personal class.

```
template <class T>
class stack{
public:
    stack(T);
    ~stack();
    void insert(T);
    T pop();
    void printstack();
private:
    int top;
    int capacity;
    T *list;
};

template <class T>
stack<T>::stack(T first){

    top=0;
    capacity=10;
    list = new T[capacity];
    memset(cards, 0, sizeof(T)*10);
    list[0]=first;
}
```

and I wanted make a stack with card method

```
class node{
    public:
    node(int i=0,int j=0);
    ~node();
    private:
        int node_num;
        int nodenum;
};

class list{
    public:
    list();
    ~list();
    private:
    stack<node> nodelist;
};

list::list(){
    stack<node> nodelist(node(1,1));
}
```

But when I run the code error shows up

"Constructor for 'deck' must explicitly initialize the member 'decklist' which does not have a default constructor"

it works fine when I use stack deck1(1); what might be the problem?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The error is about the class `deck` but you haven't shown that class. I have an idea what is wrong but I'd rather not guess. Please add the `deck` class to the posted code.

Comment: `memset(cards, 0, sizeof(T)*10);` ruins all the objects in the cards array.

Comment: My guess is `stack<card> decklist(card(1,1));` this line was intended to initialize the member variable decklist (im guessing because you havent shown the deck class), but instead this is initializing a local variable of the same name, you should use the initializer list instead.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake it was first time I am posting a question.

Comment: With `cards = new T[capacity]` you already create `capacity` instances of `card` for which the default constructor is called, that's most certainly not what you want to do. And as already mention using `memset` on a none POD object like `card` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want to create your own stack that also works with none POD objects you would need to use placement new and manual copying/moving of objects in case of a resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote this

```
deck::deck(){
    stack<card> decklist(card(1,1));
}
```

but that just declares a variable in your constructor called `decklist` which is different from the `decklist` in your class.

To initialise the `decklist` in your class you should use an *initialiser list*. Like this

```
deck::deck() : decklist(card(1,1)) {
}
```

Comment: @ㅣ기범 No worries, I've seen far worse, and you did fix it.